mySQL not save the correct data
I'm trying to create a task app. when saving it, the server says successful
[{"taskName":"Join Group","completed":true},{"taskName":"Follow Channel","completed":true},{"taskName":"Follow Twitter","completed":false},{"taskName":"Visit Website","completed":false},{"taskName":"Visit Launchpad","completed":false}]

However, it is not saved in the database, see the follow channel task
[{"taskName": "Join Group", "completed": true}, {"taskName": "Follow Channel", "completed": false}, {"taskName": "Follow Twitter", "completed": false}, {"taskName": "Visit Website", "completed": false}, {"taskName": "Visit Launchpad", "completed": false}]

Here the UI
const handleTaskClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>, taskName: string, link: string, isTaskCompleted: boolean) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!isTaskCompleted && username) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', JSON.stringify({ taskName }));

      axios.post('/api/completeTask', { username, taskName })
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Updated Task Data:', response.data);
          setTaskData(response.data);
          window.open(link, '_blank');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error completing task', error.response?.data || error.message);
        });
    }
  };


and here the backend
// models/Task.js

const { sequelize, DataTypes } = require("../config/mysql-sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Task = sequelize.define('Task', {
    username: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    tasks: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      defaultValue: []
    },
    claimedAmount: { type: DataTypes.FLOAT, defaultValue: 0 }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });

  return Task;
};

//  routes/task.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { Task } = require('../models');

const getTasksConfig = () => {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../config/tasks.json');
  if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
    try {
      return JSON.parse(fileContent);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
      return [];
    }
  } else {
    console.error('File not found:', filePath);
    return [];
  }
};


router.get('/tasksConfig', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tasksConfig = getTasksConfig();
    res.json(tasksConfig);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error loading tasks configuration' });
  }
});

// Endpoint untuk mendapatkan data tugas pengguna
router.get('/taskData', async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.query;
  try {
    const taskData = await Task.findOne({ where: { username } });
    if (taskData) {
      res.json(taskData);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'Task data not found' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
  }
});

router.post('/completeTask', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, taskName } = req.body;

  console.log(`Received request to complete task: ${taskName} for user: ${username}`);

  try {
    const tasksConfig = getTasksConfig();
    const taskConfig = tasksConfig.find(t => t.taskName === taskName);

    if (!taskConfig) {
      console.log(`Task configuration not found for taskName: ${taskName}`);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid task name' });
    }

    let taskData = await Task.findOne({ where: { username } });

    if (!taskData) {
      console.log(`No task data found for username: ${username}. Creating new task data.`);
      taskData = new Task({
        username,
        tasks: tasksConfig.map(t => ({ taskName: t.taskName, completed: false })),
        claimedAmount: 0,
      });
    } else {
      console.log(`Existing task data found for username: ${username}`);
      const existingTaskNames = taskData.tasks.map(t => t.taskName);
      const newTasks = tasksConfig.filter(t => !existingTaskNames.includes(t.taskName));
      if (newTasks.length > 0) {
        console.log(`Adding new tasks: ${JSON.stringify(newTasks)}`);
        taskData.tasks.push(...newTasks.map(t => ({ taskName: t.taskName, completed: false })));
      }
    }

    const task = taskData.tasks.find(t => t.taskName === taskName);

    if (task) {
      if (!task.completed) {
        console.log(`Completing task: ${taskName} for user: ${username}`);
        task.completed = true;
        taskData.claimedAmount += taskConfig.reward;

        await taskData.save();
        console.log(`Task completed. Updated task data: ${JSON.stringify(taskData)}`);
        res.json(taskData);
      } else {
        console.log(`Task: ${taskName} already completed for user: ${username}`);
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Task already completed' });
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Task: ${taskName} not found in task data for user: ${username}`);
      res.status(400).json({ message: 'Task not found' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error completing task:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
  }
});



router.get('/getTaskAmount', async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.query;

  try {
    const taskData = await Task.findOne({ where: { username } });

    if (taskData) {
      res.json({ claimedAmount: taskData.claimedAmount });
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;


What causes data not to be saved correctly to the database?

Take a look at your network tab. Is the correct data being sent to the server? If yes, remove all frontend code from this question as it's irrelevant. If no, remove all backend code.
